# Ban an IP when the server received an amount of data from it

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, denial-of-service

## What I need :

There are many result for adding a drop rules by an amount of request per laps of time, but I need to drop by received byte count from a particular address over a period of time.

## What I investigated :

I looked at iptables : for the first case, I saw a dedicated [match](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO.html#toc3.16). I also saw the [quota match](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.13) but, the data count is tracked globally.
I have no idea on how to mix the two rules to track the received data per IP.

## Other things :

I'm aware tracking the byte count per IP can use a lot of amount of memory, that's why I also want to keep the period short.
I can accepts other methods, as long as there's a detailed example for it.

Comment: Maybe something based on iftop and fail2ban?

Comment: @vn. : I was thinking to the firewall daemon :`Firewalld`. I don't have any clue for fail2ban *(I can't see how I can get the amount of data at the [Network layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer) with logs files, but if you have any idea, please write an answer)*.

Comment: was thinking of using watchd to check out the output of iftop and then, grep/cut the proper data, extract it and feed it to idk, nagios that runs a script or fail2ban that will...ban.

Comment: @vn. : I also saw [this](http://ipset.netfilter.org/), which look more suitable and is developed by the same team of iptables. Same thing, :-( I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use IPSET with timeout and counter options.
This will be seem like this:

```
#create ipset for accounting with default lifetime 300 secs
ipset create IP_QUOTA_SET hash:ip timeout 300 counters

#create separated rule chain
iptables --new-chain PER_IP_QUOTING

#send packets to chain
iptables -t filter -A INPUT \
  -i <in-iface> --dst <ip>  \
  -p tcp --dport <dstport>  \
  -j PER_IP_QUOTING

#if ip doesn't exist in the set, add it
iptables -t filter -A PER_IP_QUOTING    \
  -m set ! --match-set IP_QUOTA_SET src \
  -j SET --add-set IP_QUOTA_SET src --timeout 300

#if packet exists in the set, check bytes
#if byte counter > quota then close connection
#by sending of tcp-reset packet.
iptables -t filter -A PER_IP_QUOTING    \
  -m set --match-set IP_QUOTA_SET src   \
  --bytes-gt 1000 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-rst

#pass other packets (for debug purpose)
iptables -t filter -A PER_IP_QUOTING \
  -j RETURN
```

In this case you can check the list and edit it by ipset command.
Show current list with counters and timeouts: ipset list IP_QUOTA_SET.

For details read the documentation.

Comment: Nice ! I guess `--bytes-gr` should read `--bytes-gt`